# JavaFX-8 GUI for desktop apps: Are there Look & Feels like in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, javafx-8

In Swing, there were some Look & Feels provided as a part of Java, e.g.:

**Cross Platform:**

- Nimbus
- Motif
- Metal

**Specific to platforms:**

- GTK+
- Windows XP
- etc.

Does Java 8 supply Look & Feels for JavaFX like it did for Swing? (I don't ask about a specific Look & Feel, I ask in general if there are Look & Feels additional to the default one)

Comment: You can create your own L&F with css styling or use existing themes - see for example: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/scene-builder-2/user-guide/stylesheet-support.htm

Comment: [AquaFX](http://aquafx-project.com/index.html) provides a third-party Mac OS look and feel.

Comment: Well... if you want Those LaF's, why would you even use JavaFX then? I mean, tjere is a Swing.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. @assylias , is it possible to use these existing css "themes" without the GUI builder? I.e. - Are they a part of java and I can define somewhere in the code to use one of them?

Comment: Are there currently only 2 themes? (Caspian, Modena) ?

Comment: The themes listed in SceneBuilder - modena, modena touch, modena high contrast, caspian, caspian embedded are all shipped with the JavaFX 8 runtime.  Several [third party themes](http://www.guigarage.com/javafx-themes/) are provided by guigarage, e.g. [AeroFX](http://www.aerofx.org), [flatter](http://www.guigarage.com/javafx-themes/flatter/) and the aforementioned AquaFX.  A GUI builder (such as SceneBuilder) is not necessary to use any of the mentioned themes.

Comment: If you like to post your comments as an answer it will be very nice (and I'll of course accept it)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will answer my own question with a summary of the responses to this question and with a little research I made by myself:

- In JavaFX, there is no Look & Feel term anymore, but there are **Stylesheets**
- Until JavaFX-8 (I.e. the Java 8 version), there was only one provided stylesheet, named **Caspian**
- Starting from JavaFX-8, another stylesheet was added, named **Modena**. The **Modena** stylesheet **is the default one in JavaFX-8**

It is possible in to switch between **Modena** and **Caspian** stylesheets using the following commands:

```
setUserAgentStylesheet(STYLESHEET_CASPIAN); // Switches to "Caspian"
setUserAgentStylesheet(STYLESHEET_MODENA);  // Switches to "Modena"
```

Note that:

- `setUserAgentStylesheet(String url)` is a method of the class `Application`
- The constants `STYLESHEET_CASPIAN` and `STYLESHEET_MODENA` are class members of `Application`
- The code shown above should be called on the JavaFX `Application` thread
- `STYLESHEET_CASPIAN` and `STYLESHEET_MODENA` contain **url**s. You may use your own stylesheets using the method, passing it the url to your stylesheet

  - For example, if I created a stylesheet named **DarkTheme.css** and placed it in the project directory, under **src/resources**, I would use the following code to apply it:
    `setUserAgentStylesheet(this.getClass().getResource("resources/DarkTheme.css").toExternalForm());`
  - If you just want to **extend** the current stylesheet, and not to define it all from scratch, you may use instead:
    `scene.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("resources/DarkTheme.css").toExternalForm());`